# ArrayList, Each object can only exist in one ArrayList at a time

Tags: java

I have two simple classes, NetworkDevice.java and Channel.java

in Channel.java i have

```
private ArrayList<Channel> channel = new ArrayList<Channel>();
```

which i am trying to change to store only NetworkDevices

The specification i am trying to get is:

> Each NetworkDevice has the ability to join a Channel, but can only
>   exist in one Channel at a time.

NetworkDevice.java is shown below

```
    public class NetworkDevice {

    // Fields
    private String address;
    //Constructor
    public NetworkDevice(String address, Channel channel){
        this.address = address;
        addToChannel(channel);
    }

    // Add a NetworkDevice to the 
    public void addToChannel(Channel channel){
            channel.addChannel(this);
    }
}
```

Channel.java shown below

```
   import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Channel {

    // Fields
    private ArrayList<Channel> channel = new ArrayList<Channel>();
    private int number;
    private List<Packet> packet;

    /*
     * Constructor
     * Initializes the number of the the Channel
     * Allows for a packet to be passed in
     */
    public Channel(int number, Packet packets) {
        this.number = number;
        packet.add(packets);
    }

    /*
     * Adds to the Channel array
     * @Param a network device object
     */
    public void addChannel(NetworkDevice device) {
        channel.add(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the question though?

Comment: Would putting the joined channel into the NetworkDevice be an option? The channel being an `Optional` would solve that.

Comment: How would this work? and the question is the specification

Comment: What exactly is `addChannel(NetworkDevice device)` doing? You do nothing with `device` and you add "this" Channel to your channel list...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you messed up quite a few names and concepts there.

I rewrote the code a bit so it makes sense to me. That is, me,  without any real clue what is to be achieved. But see what results my code brings:

```
public class MultiInst {
    static public class NetworkDevice {
        private final String    mAddress;
        private Channel         mCurrentChannel = null;

        public NetworkDevice(final String address, final Channel channel) {
            this.mAddress = address;
            addToChannel(channel);
        }

        public void addToChannel(final Channel channel) {
            if (mCurrentChannel == channel) return; // may do this
            if (mCurrentChannel != channel && mCurrentChannel != null) mCurrentChannel.removeNetworkDevice(this);

            mCurrentChannel = channel;
            mCurrentChannel.addNetworkDevice(this);
        }

        @Override public String toString() {
            return mAddress;
        }
    }


    static public class Channel {

        private final ArrayList<NetworkDevice>  mNetworkDevices = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<Packet>              mPackets        = new ArrayList<>();
        private final int                       mNumber;

        public Channel(final int number, final Packet... packets) {
            this.mNumber = number;
            if (packets != null) for (final Packet p : packets) {
                mPackets.add(p);
            }
        }

        public void addNetworkDevice(final NetworkDevice device) {
            mNetworkDevices.add(device);
        }
        public void removeNetworkDevice(final NetworkDevice device) {
            mNetworkDevices.remove(device);
        }

        @Override public String toString() {
            String acc = "Channel #" + mNumber + ":\t";
            if (mNetworkDevices.size() < 1) return acc + " [EMPTY] ";
            for (final NetworkDevice c : mNetworkDevices) {
                acc += "\t" + c;
            }
            return acc;
        }
    }



    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Channel c1 = new Channel(1);
        final Channel c2 = new Channel(2);
        final NetworkDevice d = new NetworkDevice("lol", null);

        System.out.println("Start\n");

        System.out.println(c1);
        System.out.println(c2);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Adding to channel 1...");
        d.addToChannel(c1);
        System.out.println(c1);
        System.out.println(c2);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Adding to channel 2...");
        d.addToChannel(c2);
        System.out.println(c1);
        System.out.println(c2);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("End");
    }

}
```

will create the output

```
Start

Channel #1:  [EMPTY] 
Channel #2:  [EMPTY] 

Adding to channel 1...
Channel #1:     lol
Channel #2:  [EMPTY] 

Adding to channel 2...
Channel #1:  [EMPTY] 
Channel #2:     lol

End
```